# Should I use relative or absolute url on my website?

Tags: html, hyperlink

If I'm not moving my site around, any good reason for why I should use absolute URL's over relative?

Answer (score 3):

Absolute URL's will work no matter if you move the content from folder to folder, however each language will have a way to reference a BASE URL in one way or another.

For example if you have "test/1.html" as a URL on index.html it will redirect to /test/1.html however if you copy that link to /dom/index.html it will redirect to /dom/test/1.html

It would be best practice to use the base URL and then the relative URL e.g. {BASE URL}/test/1.html

Answer (score 1):

I tend to prefer using relative because if you ever make any changes to the site relative urls tend to be much more adaptable.

If you are talking about efficiency, there is no real difference between the two.

Comment: Remember that if you use absolute urls and change the folder you have to change the url to account for the new path. With relative urls you don't have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> If I'm not moving my site around [...]

This will come up one day. Even if you're just moving your site from one folder to another, you want the links to be relative. You may not think that will ever happen, but it's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: I'm developing sites using WP, so I have to update links anyway. + when screen scraping sites, the URL will be wrong (mysite + relative url). I'm currently screen scraping partner sites in order to show specific info when I ran into this problem.

Comment: There's always a way to make the links work automatically. You can even use "routing", so e.g. one PHP file pulls from others depending on the arguments. I think it's worth the effort to make sure you don't mess with links anymore.

Comment: A base tag set from a config file makes using absolute URLs easy and portable.